# .wsp webpart does not display German umlauts

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part

I have a .wsp webpart which pastes a string of text into the site collection sharing dialog window upon loading. Unfortunately, all German umlauts are displayed as �.

Umlauts which are ISO-8859-1 are falsely interpreted as UTF-8.

Is there anything I can do in the javascript code of the webpart to change that?`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at the .cs/.resx (whatever) file where you define those strings. Try changing the file encoding to UTF-8, save, redeploy.

Comment: The webpart is a third party webpart and when I open it in SP Designer it only contains a .js file. I'm not familiar with .cs .resx files as I'm not a programmer. Can I easily add this to the .wsp package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the javascript code, what it is doing and whether the settings of the page are overruled by http-header.

You could firstly examine whether your webpart uses css-classes. If there is a reference to a css-file in the js-file you could try to change [charset property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_charset_rule.asp) there. Closer to a solution using the same encoding everywhere is of course to save the given files with the expected encoding as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720885/showing-umlauts-in-html-with-utf8-charset)

An overview about the different steps and their effects is given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982985/printing-out-mutated-vowel-with-css).
And if really nothing else helps than having a workaround setting the output by js than you could manipulate the output by a regex replacing those letters with hex code like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694945/javascript-regex-replace-has-to-keep-german-mutated-vowels)

Comment: Thanks, re-saving the .js file in UTF-8 worked wonders. I found out that by editing the file directly in SP Designer it would change the encoding somehow although it's still being shown as UTF-8. If I open the file from SP Designer (open with) in VS Code, I can edit it and just re-save it (maintaining UTF-8) and it works.